# C++ reading string using more delimiters

Tags: c++

I'm quite new to c++. My problem is that I have a string that can be any length and ends with \n. For example:

`const string s = "Daniel,20;Michael,99\n"`
(It's always "name,age;name,age;name,age.............\n")

and I want to separate name and age and put it into two vectors so it can be stored. But I dont know how to manage string with more separators. So the example would be separated like this:

*Vector name contains {Daniel,Michael}*

*Vector age contains {20,99}*

Comment: weirdly, `std::getline` can be used for this

Comment: You _usually_ don't actually want two vectors. You usually want one vector of structs.

Comment: just split the string with one delimiter then again with the other. its not much more complicated than having a single delimiter

Comment: Does this do what you want? https://onlinegdb.com/54-C_pSfh

Comment: [std::string::find_first_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) might be useful here.

Comment: @mooingduck that's OO thinking. Not always the best.

Comment: Upon further review, I'd consider a regex for this.

Comment: @JHBonarius: While I acknowledge it might be good to have two vectors in some cases, I've never yet encountered that situation.

Comment: @MooingDuck It's called "data oriented design". There is a cppcon talk by Matt Godbolt where he compares OO, Data Oriented and Functional styles if you are interested https://youtu.be/HG6c4Kwbv4I

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stringstream` and `getline` for this purpose, but since you have a very specific format, simple `std::string::find` is likely to fix your issue. Here is a simple example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstddef>

int main() {
    std::string const s = "Daniel,20;Michael,99;Terry,42;Jack,34";

    std::vector<std::string> names;
    std::vector<int> ages;

    std::size_t beg = 0;
    std::size_t end = 0;
    while ((end = s.find(',', end)) != s.npos) {
        names.emplace_back(s, beg, end - beg);
        char* pend;
        ages.push_back(std::strtol(s.c_str() + end + 1, &pend, 10));
        end = beg = pend - s.c_str() + 1;
    }

    for (auto&& n : names) std::puts(n.c_str());

    for (auto&& a : ages) std::printf("%d\n", a);

}
```

Comment: Usually we want answers to describe the problem, the solution, and the why, rather than simply showing code.

Comment: @MooingDuck I was so preoccupied by trying to solve this with compile-time regex that I quickly put out this version. Thank you for your feedback. I tried to add some explanation.

Comment: I still like `operator>>` myself. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d9c58c42881558a

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my C++ skills have faded, but this is what I would do :-

```
vector <string> names;
vector <string> ages;
string inputString = "Daniel,20;Michael,99;Terry,42;Jack,34";

string word = "";
for(int i = 0; i<inputString.length(); i++)
{
    
    if(inputString[i] == ';')
    {
        ages.push_back(word);
        word = "";
    }
    
    else if (inputString[i] == ',')
    {
        names.push_back(word);
        word = "";
    }
    
    else
    {
        word = word + inputString[i];
    }
}
ages.push_back(word);
```